# Vuetify Navigation Drawer issues with clipped and drawer size

Tags: vuetify.js, navigation-drawer

I have a couple of problems with Navigation Drawer that I hope someone can advise on please.

https://codepen.io/hobbeschild/pen/MWeXpey

1. I thought "clipped" was supposed to make the drawer appear under the app bar, but it appears on top of it.
2. If the containing card is given a short height, the drawer is also restricted to this height (which can give it a scrollbar).  Can the drawer always have its height and width just bigger than its contents?

HTML:

```html
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-card class="mx-auto overflow-hidden" height="100" width="344">
          <v-app-bar color="deep-purple accent-4" dark>
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
            <v-toolbar-title>My files</v-toolbar-title>
          </v-app-bar>
          <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" absolute bottom temporary clipped>
            <v-list nav dense>
              <v-list-item-group v-model="group" active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-4">
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-title>Foo</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-title>Bar</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-title>Fizz</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-title>Buzz</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list>
          </v-navigation-drawer>
          <v-card-text>
            The navigation drawer will appear from the bottom on smaller size screens.
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-app>
    </div>
```

JS:

```js
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        drawer: false,
        group: null
      }),
    
      watch: {
        group() {
          this.drawer = false;
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I ended up logging an issue regarding clipped and it was closed ref this:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6141

The styling solution does work.  Still looking for the drawer size solution...

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think you want to enclose nav elements in a card. Try placing the card underneath the nav drawer in the markup.
2. Add clipped-left to the `v-app-bar` component.
3. Remove `absolute` from `v-navigation-drawer`.